# How to used trp.trp2 package inside AWS lambda as layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am created trp.trp2 layer in AWS lambda but that layer is not working for my lambda code to import below package :

```
import trp.trp2 as t2
```

I used this command to create trp.trp2 package for AWS lambda layer  :

```
python -m pip install amazon-textract-response-parser -t.
```

How to used trp.trp2 package inside AWS lambda as layer ? (For python code only)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information to get a meaningful response.  How did you create your layer?  Is it a zip file, what does the folder structure look like in the zip file?  What error do you get when you try and use it?  For example see this Q -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73602045/unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-undefined-symbol-pyint-fromlong